# Java: Client does not read stream from server

Tags: java, sockets, stream, client-server

Im making a login system with the client-server architecture. I wrote the streams and socket variables at the top of the classes to avoid too much code. My server starts normally,without errors. But the client side does absolute nothing! It doesn't read from server.

What's wrong?

**Server**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

DataInputStream clientIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream serverOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


public static void main(DataInputStream clientIn, DataOutputStream serverOut)throws Exception, java.lang.Exception {

            String string = "";
            String string2 = "";
            String username = "admin";
            String password = "123";
            boolean loggedIn = false;

            while(!loggedIn){
                while(!string.equals(username)) {
                    serverOut.writeUTF("Enter username:");
                    string = clientIn.readUTF();
                    if (string.equals(username)) {
                        while (!string2.equals(password)) {
                            serverOut.writeUTF("Enter password:");
                            string2 = clientIn.readUTF();
                            if (string2.equals(password)) {
                                serverOut.writeUTF("Login Successful");
                                loggedIn = true;
                            } else {
                                serverOut.writeUTF("Invalid password try again");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        serverOut.writeUTF("Invalid username try again");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("client says: " + string);
            }
    }
```

**Client**

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 40000);
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


public static void main(DataInputStream dataInputStream, DataOutputStream dataOutputStream) {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String string = "", string2 = "";
            boolean loggedIn = false;

            while (true) {
                string2 = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                System.out.println(string2);
                if(string2.equals("Login Successful")){
                    loggedIn = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(string2.equals("Invalid username try again")||string2.equals("Invalid password try again")){
                    string = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(string);
                }
                string = br.readLine();
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(string);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
            }
    }
```

Comment: I think that part of the problem is that you're using a DataInputStream rather than a Reader. You need to read text.